# Storing request body as global variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I have a project that requires the use of requests and is using javascript run by node. I am having trouble storing the body of a request to a global variable so I can access it in other functions. Is there a way to save the response in a global variable? Thanks.

```
var request = require('request');

var globalBody = "";

var options = {
    url: 'http://www.google.com/',
    headers: {
      'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_1_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10B350 Safari/8536.25'
    }
}
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
   if(error != null){
       console.log('error:', error);
   }
   if(response.statusCode != 200){
       console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
   }else{
       globalBody = body;
   }
});


console.log(globalBody)
```

The last line "console.log(globalBody)" results in "" but I want it to display the body of the request. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use window.localStorage to store globally

Answer (score 0):

console.log(globalBody) gets called before the request method callback. globalBody value gets updated but after you are trying to print it.Try the following code it will work.

```
var request = require('request');

var globalBody = "";

var options = {
    url: 'http://www.google.com/',
    headers: {
      'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_1_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10B350 Safari/8536.25'
    }
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
   if(error != null){
       console.log('error:', error);
   }
   if(response.statusCode != 200){
       console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
   }else{
       globalBody = body;
       console.log(globalBody);
   }
});
```

You need to call other functions after the successful completion of async request to use global variables in it.